Drop down multiple list selection in asp.net
This is the default dropdown single select no checkbox no button list code (In WebAPP.NET framework):
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ODWConnectionString_Live %>"
                                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(NULLIF(CZF_ODW, 'NA'), 'Other') AS CZF_ODW FROM dbo.WebAppTestView;"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                            <td class="required" align="right" style="text-align: right;">
                             <span class="catchment">Catchment Zone:</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlField1" runat="server" CssClass="textfield" Width="200px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlField1_SelectedIndexChanged" style="width: 182px; margin: 9px;"
                                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="CZF_ODW" DataValueField="CZF_ODW" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="All"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList> 
                             </td>
                             </td>

Need to convert above dropdown list code to multiple selection checkbox dropdown list with button.

You told us your requirements but you failed to show us your attempt at meeting your objective, nor did you explain what problem or error you encountered in your attempt.  Please edit your question and show us your best attempt and then add details about the problem / error.

Well, if possible, using a list box allows multiple selections, but of course takes up more screen space.
There is no built-in multiple select combo box (DropDownList) in asp.net.
So, you can adopt a 3rd party library. A rather common choice is the jQuery add-in called select2.
The next issue is that the select2 add-in does not play nice with the asp.net DropDownList, but it does work just fine if you drop in a HTML "select" element.
And it turns out that the DropDownList is based on the HTML select element anyway. In fact, if you tag the select with a runat="server", then you have quite much the same functionally as the Drop-down list. The only feature missing is autopostback="true". And you not noted if you need this ability.
Let's build an example, and assume that we need auto-post backs for the combo box.
To do this, we add a JavaScript onchange event (client side), and we simply click a button on the form. That button should (eventually) be hidden with a style="display:none".
So, our markup looks like this:
        <div style="float: left">

            <h4>Select Multiple Cites</h4>

            <select id="DropDownList1" runat="server" clientidmode="static"
                datatextfield="City"
                multiple="true"
                style="width: 500px"
                onchange="mychange()">
            </select>

            <script>
                function mychange() {
                    $('#Button1').click()
                }
            </script>
        </div>

        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 40px">

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Hotels"
                ClientIDMode="Static"
                CssClass="btn"
                OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both; height: 20px"></div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" Width="40%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>



        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {

                console.log("on page load select2 combo box setup")
                $('#DropDownList1').select2()

            });

        </script>

And our code behind is this:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadData()
    Dim rstHotels As DataTable
    rstHotels = MyRst("SELECT City FROM tblHotels
                       WHERE City is not null
                       GROUP BY City")

    DropDownList1.DataSource = rstHotels
    DropDownList1.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    LoadGrid()

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA"

    Dim strWhere As String = ""

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand()

    Dim ParamCount As Integer = 0
    Dim sP As String = ""

    For Each MyPick As ListItem In DropDownList1.Items
        Debug.Print($"Item = {MyPick.Text} selected = {MyPick.Selected}")
        If MyPick.Selected Then
            If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= ","
            ParamCount += 1
            sP = $"@P{ParamCount}"
            strWhere &= sP
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add($"@P{ParamCount}", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = MyPick.Text
        End If
    Next

    If strWhere <> "" Then
        strSQL &= $" WHERE City IN ({strWhere}) "
    End If

    strSQL &= " ORDER BY HotelName"

    cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL

    Dim dt As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()


End Sub

Note that in above, we still used SQL parameters, and thus the code is safe from potential SQL injections.

Of course, if you don't need nor want the auto-post back, then you can remove the button, and the onchange JavaScript code attached to the select element.
So, above assumes you have jQuery installed (most do), and you have to then add the jQuery select2. That add-in can be found here:
https://select2.org/
I also suggest dumping the use of SqlDataSource(s) in the markup, since the very instant you want code control over filtering etc., then use of a SqlDataSource becomes rather difficult to use, but more important is difficult to control when such data sources are to be consumed, or to trigger loading of data.
I thus became rather tired of typing connection code over and over, and thus I have a number of global application helper routines.
The 2 helper routines used in above are MyRst, and MyRstP.
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String, ByVal Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = My.Settings.TEST4
    End If

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function

Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand, ByVal Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = My.Settings.TEST4
    End If

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function

